# Raster turns black and white in ArcMap

Tags: qgis, raster, arcmap, classification, scp

So, I have been doing land use classification using SCP in QGIS and then I exported the raster as GeoTIFF file. I try to open this raster in ArcMap but it shows black and white and no classification results. Below is the pic. The first one is QGIS and the second one is ArcMap

[image: the raster in QGIS after classification using SCP]
[image: the same raster in ArcMap shows black and white and no classification]

What is wrong here?

Comment: Have you tried adjusting the symbology in Arc?

Comment: I have tried it. I changed it to 'classified' from 'stretched' but it showed the same

Comment: Change to unique renderer, set classes 0, 1, 2 & 3 to whatever colours you want and label them accordingly and set -999 to transparent.

Comment: Above and beyond statistics and a proper NODATA, there also seems to be a rotation difference, this isn't as simple an issue as the Question suggests.

Comment: I would guess that the rotation is not an issue, the QGIS project is probably just in another CRS than the ArcGIS project.

Comment: Did ArcGIS build pyramids (overviews) for the raster?  It's default interpolation for this is very buggy and often results in output like this.  You should rebuild pyramids using a different interpolation algorithm.